# Telegram, tracking message edit/delete and editing my own messages (Client, not Bot API)

Tags: telegram, mtproto

So I'm trying to implement the logging of telegram chats into my ELK storage in a proper way, and the existing solution with tgcli is too old (I also have a PoC which logs message edits from Android client via Xposed, but its implemented on top of UI level and is ineffective)

I need to receive edits/deletion of messages, and do it with client Telegram API.

Spent a day on researching it:

- support for editing messages appeared in [May 15, 2016 (telegram blog)](https://telegram.org/blog/edit)
- telegram-cli's [tgl](https://github.com/vysheng/tgl) library is 2 years old and most likely has no support for that layer
- I looked into telegramdesktop source as it was very promising, unfortunately their [git history](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/commits/master/Telegram/Resources/scheme.tl) has no scheme changes poiting to edit support.
- And the [official layer version list](https://core.telegram.org/api#updates-log) is truncated. Security via obscurity eh.
- from some tests done with golang library used in [shelomentsevd/telegramgo](https://github.com/shelomentsevd/telegramgo), edits in supergroup are handled by TL_updateChannelTooLong message

Now I  don't want to lose more time picking the libraries/sources. So, I'm asking about the experience with either of the following libraries, I'm looking for exactly one library which will allow to implement the required features fast - for someone who doesn't want to dive deep into [MTProto's specifics](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto).

- [sochix/TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) is missing explicit examples about getting edits. Probably would be hard
- [danog/MadelineProto](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto) seems like a good place to start
- there are also [tdlib](https://tlgrm.ru/docs/tdlib), [libqtelegram](https://github.com/Aseman-Land/libqtelegram-aseman-edition), [TelegramAPI](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramApi)

Comment: Have you tried Telethon (Python)? It supports message [edit](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/events-reference.html#messageedited) and [delete](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/events-reference.html#messagedeleted) events

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to do it in [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/).

Here is a sample code I've put together gathering snippets directly from the docs.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

API_ID = ...
API_HASH = " ... "

client = TelegramClient('session', api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH)

@client.on(events.MessageDeleted)
async def handler(event):
    # Log all deleted message IDs
    for msg_id in event.deleted_ids:
        print('Message', msg_id, 'was deleted in', event.chat_id)

@client.on(events.MessageEdited)
async def handler(event):
    # Log the date of new edits
    print('Message', event.id, 'changed at', event.date)


with client:
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Docs for: [MessageEdited](https://web.archive.org/web/20211209163259/https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.messageedited.MessageEdited), [MessageDeleted](https://web.archive.org/web/20211209163259/https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.messagedeleted.MessageDeleted))